# ActiveSync 2.5 push contacts Android 2.3 and 4

Tags: android, push, activesync

I am building a groupware using zpush to sync contacts/calendars. Direct Push is working very well on any IOS device but does not on Android (tested on 2.3 and 4.0).

Instead of receiving a SYNC command after a PING response (status 2 - modified), I receive a FOLDERSYNC command from the device. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the device is free to send a `FolderSync` command at almost any time. Just because the `Ping`'s return code indicates that there are changes for the device to synchronize, you should probably not expect it to happen all the time.

As you're finding out, there are subtle but significant differences between the popular EAS implementations, and it's a complex protocol to boot. Your server's code will have to be pretty forgiving if you want all EAS clients to work happily with it.